# Back Up Documents Folder to iCloud

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, icloud, nsdocument

My app builds PDFs unique to each individual.  Since they cannot be easily recreated, and would need to be used on multiple devices, I want them to be backed up to be iCloud.  The ideal situation would be that they are made on one device, and when downloaded with same Apple ID on another device, all of the documents are already there.  How do I accomplish this?  I have iCloud enabled on the APP ID, but there is nothing to configure there, and everything I have seen so far on this subject is how to stop it from backing up to iCloud.  I thought this would mean that it does it automatically, but when I install on different devices, the documents are not there.  What do I need to be doing?  Is there some extra step in coding that needs to take place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing two different things:

- Backup of an individual device to iCloud (Backup)
- Sharing/syncing of data by an app with other instances of itself through iCloud (Documents and Data)

You want to look into the latter if you expect to upload from your app on one device and download to the same app for the same iCloud account on another device.

Comment: Ok...so I definitely want to look into the latter, but how is that possible